# Add/re-add buttons to toolbar in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, toolbar

I accidentally removed the "Create new Class" button in eclipse. How would I get it back onto the top toolbar? I've looked through all the menus and I cant find an option to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just right-click on your perspective (top right corner default) and choose Customize.

There you can select and deselect toolbar icons.
Java Element Creation -> New Java Project/Package/Class

hf

Comment: Yes but I cannot add more types

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse 4.4, choose **Window->Customize perspective**. First tab (**Tool Bar Visibility**) allows to customize toolbar buttons.